# Магия регулярных выражений Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Парсим строку, представляющую собой правило для Snort.

```
#alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 25 (msg:"ET EXPLOIT Possible Sendmail SpamAssassin Milter Plugin Remote Arbitrary Command Injection Attempt"; flow:established,to_server; content:"to|3A|"; depth:10; nocase; content:"+\"|7C|"; distance:0; reference:url,www.securityfocus.com/bid/38578; reference:url,seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Mar/140; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2010941; classtype:attempted-user; sid:2010941; rev:1; metadata:created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2010_07_30;)
```

На выходе одним из элементов словаря будут такие данные

```
{'data': '+\\"|7C|', 'distance': '  0'}
```

Видим, что добавился лишний символ "\", из-за чего не получается добавить запись в базу данных postgresql. Есть ли какой - то способ положить эти данные в базу без учета второго слэша, либо использовать какое - то преобразование благодаря которому запись создаться в базе. Если скопировать данные и положить их в базу руками, но с одним символом слэша, то все хорошо

```
def Parse_options(rule):
    options = re.findall(r'([a-z0-9_]+): *(.+?);', str(rule))
    names_options_value = list(options)
```

В базу добавляю так

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO all_field VALUES ('" + field_header[0] + "', '" + field_header[1] + "', '" + field_header[2] + "', '" + field_header[3] + "', '" + field_header[4] + "', '" + field_header[5] + "', '" + field_header[6] + "', '" + r'{fields_options}' +"', '" + flag_comment+"');")
con.commit()
```

Где fields_options - это преобразованный к строке результат работы регулярки

```
{"msg": "ET EXPLOIT Possible Sendmail SpamAssassin Milter Plugin Remote Arbitrary Command Injection Attempt",
 "flow": {"established": "true", "to_server": "true"},
 "content": [{"data": "to|3A|", "depth": "  10"}, {"data": "+\\"|7C|", "distance": "  0"}],
 "reference": "url doc.emergingthreats.net/2010941",
 "classtype": "attempted-user",
 "sid": "2010941",
 "rev": "1",
 "metadata": ["created_at 2010_07_30", " updated_at 2010_07_30"]
}
```

Comment: Запись в базу надо делать по-человечески, а не регулярки мучать.

Comment: в базе должна лежать вот такая строка content:"+\"|7C|". Есть какое-то более объективное решение проблемы с использованием регулярным выражений?

Comment: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Comment: Если надо сделать регулярное выражение, то приведите однозначное описание: примеры текстов и что в них найти

Comment: А как вы его в базу посылаетте?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не вклеивайте значения в запрос.
Используйте prepared-statements и bind-param. Оно еще и быстрей и безопасней выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

Лишний `\` не добавляется на самом деле, а только отображается при печати, так что с регуляркой всё в порядке.

Минимальный код:

```
import re

s = r'#alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 25 (msg:"ET EXPLOIT Possible Sendmail SpamAssassin Milter Plugin Remote Arbitrary Command Injection Attempt"; flow:established,to_server; content:"to|3A|"; depth:10; nocase; content:"+\"|7C|"; distance:0; reference:url,www.securityfocus.com/bid/38578; reference:url,seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Mar/140; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2010941; classtype:attempted-user; sid:2010941; rev:1; metadata:created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2010_07_30;)'
```

Теперь делаем печать всего списка или только одного тапла для краткости:

```
print(re.findall(r'([a-z0-9_]+): *(.+?);', s)[4])
```

Вывод:

```
('content', '"+\\"|7C|"')
```

Но если попробовать вывести саму строку:

```
print(re.findall(r'([a-z0-9_]+): *(.+?);', s)[4][1])
```

то получим:

```
"+\"|7C|"
```

без лишних `\`.

Подробнее про символы `\` в регулярках можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33582162/13970074)